# Using same generic wildcard in 2 objects

Tags: java, generics, javafx

I am trying to copy the `CellFactory` from one `TableColumn` to another. The issue I'm running into is with generics.

The problem being that `table.getColumns()` returns a list of `TableColumn<X, ?>` and I want to create a new column, with the same `Tablecolumn<X, ?>` parameters but there is no way for me to know the second, `?` parameter.

```
for (TableColumn<X, ?> col : table.getColumns()) {
    TableColumn<X, ?> newCol = new TableColumn<>();
    newCol.setCellValueFactory(col.getCellValueFactory()); // Error <X, ?> != <X, ?>
}
```

Am I able to define a generic type that will be used in both instances? Or is this not possible due to the generic information being lost at runtime?

**Edit:**

Casting it to a `TableColumn<X, Object>` seems to work but this feels very wrong and I would rather not rely on casting to an `Object`.

```
for (TableColumn<X, ?> col : table.getColumns()) {
    TableColumn<X, Object> tempCol = (TableColumn<X, Object>) col;
    TableColumn<X, Object> newCol = new TableColumn<>();
    newCol.setCellValueFactory(tempCol.getCellValueFactory());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java wildcard stands as an unknown type. This means that two unknown types cannot be of same type. In order to tell the compiler that we are dealing with the same unknown type we need to define a temporary generic type `Y` that will bound two TableColumns to the same type. The only way we can do this is to move the creation and updating of new TableColumn into a separate parametrized method like this:

```
for ( TableColumn<X, ?> col : getColumns() ) {
        TableColumn<X, ?> newCol = create(col);
}

public <Y> TableColumn<X, ?> create(TableColumn<X, Y> tc){
    TableColumn<X, Y> newCol = new TableColumn<>();
    newCol.setCellValueFactory( tc.getCellValueFactory() );         
    return newCol;
}
```

Comment: I figured this might be the only way to do it but was hoping to not need a separate method.. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris - separate method is the only way since you can't introduce specific captures in any other way.